# Azure Data Explorer - Measuring the Cluster performance /impact

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a way to measure the impact to Kusto Cluster when we run a Query from Power BI. This is because the Query I use in Power BI might get large data even if it is for a limited time range. I am aware of setting - limit Query result record ,but I would like to measure the impact to Cluster for specific queries .

Do I need to use the metrics under - Data explorer monitoring. Is there a best way to do it and any specific metrics . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.show queries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/queries) or [Query diagnostics logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-diagnostic-logs?tabs=commands-and-queries) - these can show you the resources utilization per query (e.g. Total CPU time & memory peak), and you can filter to a specific user or application name (e.g. `PowerBI`).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs . I am checking the Query diagnostic logs and the Metrics for the cluster.

Comment: Working Example

.show Queries
| where StartedOn > ago(1d)
| extend MemoryPeak = tolong(ResourcesUtilization.MemoryPeak)
| project StartedOn, CommandType, ClientActivityId, TotalCpu, MemoryPeak
| top 10 by MemoryPeak